# Find all items through two has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, mongoid

Lets say I have a Rails app that is modelled as follows:

1. There is a HOUSE class; it has_many ROOMS
2. There is a ROOM class; it belongs_to a HOUSE and has_many FURNISHINGS
3. There is a FURNISHING class; it belongs_to a ROOM

Give this model setup, how would one find all FURNISHINGS in a given HOUSE? I would hope to be able to do something like `arbitrary_house.furnishings`.

Is this possible without adding more associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your models as follows:

house.rb

```
has_many :rooms
has_many :furnishings, :through => :rooms
```

room.rb

```
belongs_to :house
has_many :furnishings
```

furnishing.rb

```
belongs_to :room
```

Now you can say

```
arbitrary_house.furnishings
```

Also see:

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association
```

Comment: Rails and Ruby can do that. I spent two days until I found capitalize. Pre stack overflow days of mine.

Comment: Since mongoid does not support :through, I had to make the HOUSE, has_many FURNISHINGS and the FURNISHING belong_to HOUSE

Comment: So then furnishings table has room_id and house_id? Put Mongoid in the question text or title or tag please.